# fatal exception crash after changing realm version from 0.82.1 to 0.87.5 in android

Tags: android, realm, realm-migration

I'm getting this error after changing the version of realm from 0.82.1 to 0.87.5.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.xxxxx.consumer, PID: 8633
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create applicationcom.gemba.consumer.realm.AppInstance: 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Configurations cannot be different if used to open the same file. 
Cached configuration: 
                                                              realmFolder: /data/user/0/com.xxxx.consumer/files
                                                              realmFileName : default.realm
                                                              canonicalPath: /data/data/com.xxxx.consumer/files/default.realm
                                                              key: [length: 0]
                                                              schemaVersion: 0
                                                              migration: null
                                                              deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded: true
                                                              durability: FULL
                                                              schemaMediator: io.realm.DefaultRealmModuleMediator@b40b99c9
```

My realm Manager class is this
    public final class RealmManager {

```
public static RealmManager realmManager;
public static RealmConfiguration realmConfig;
public static Realm realm;
public static WorkerThread workerThread;
public static Context appContext;

public static RealmManager getInstance(Context context) {

    if (realmManager == null) {
        realmManager = new RealmManager();

        getRealmConfig(context);
        realm = Realm.getInstance(realmConfig);
        workerThread = new WorkerThread(context);
        appContext = context;
    }

    return realmManager;
}

public static RealmConfiguration getRealmConfig(Context context) {
    if (realmConfig == null) {
        realmConfig = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(context)
                .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
                .build();

    }
    return realmConfig;

}
```

and I'm using it like this in Application class.

```
RealmManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every `Realm` instance is created based on a `RealmConfiguration`.

When `getInstance()` called on a `RealmConfiguration` pointed to a Realm file (same file path) which has already been opened on another `RealmConfiugration`, the new config has to be the same with the old one.

The implementation of the `getInstance(Context context)` is like below.

```
public static Realm getInstance(Context context) {
    return Realm.getInstance(new RealmConfiguration.Builder(context)
            .name(DEFAULT_REALM_NAME)
            .build());
}
```

When you call

```
RealmManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
```

That implicitly created `RealmConfiguration` in app's files dir with the default Realm name "default.realm. And it is different from what you created in `getRealmConfig` -- no `deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()`.

To fix this, just use the same configuration returned by `getRealmConfig` everywhere. BTW, your `getRealmConfig()` is not thread-safe, you might want to fix it if it will be called in different threads.

`Realm.getInstance(Context context)` is deprecated in Realm 0.88.0.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, the error was in this particular line                      
     `workerThread = new WorkerThread(context);`

The constructor was using a different instance of realm which was causing the issue 

   `public WorkerThread(Context context) {
        this.realm = Realm.getInstance(context);
        this.workerHandler = new WorkerHandler(realm);

    }`

changed
    `Realm.getInstance(context) to RealmManager.getRealm() `
It works fine  now. 
Weird that realm V0.82.1 completely ignored it.

Anyway Thanks for the reply.